# Is there any way to ensure every component implements OnDestroy by default?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Components created by the CLI command `ng g c [COMPONENT_NAME]` automatically have the `OnInit` interface implemented. Is there any way I can customise the CLI so that it also generates components with the `OnDestroy` tacked on by default? (Preferrable via some config file) I can't seem to find anything about this in the docs.

Comment: Why? Do ALL your components do something in ngOnDestroy? If not why would you bother with the additional noise when adding and implementing the interface takes a few keystrokes at best in an IDE?

Comment: @Clashsoft Not all of them do, but a lot do implement it to unsubscribe from observables, the reason I'd like this is specifically because I often forget to add it in and leave the component susceptible to memory leaks. It's not a huge necessity but would be a nice QoL.

Comment: there is no such option out of the box, but you can create your own schematics and overwrite the default component schematics with your own. there you can make any component template you want

Comment: Ah, so you actually want a reminder to unsubscribe. Maybe the rxjs eslint plugin can help? Specifically https://github.com/cartant/eslint-plugin-rxjs/blob/main/docs/rules/no-ignored-subscription.md

Comment: If it's the subscriptions you're worried about you could implement `auto unsubscribe` which lets you decorate components. https://levelup.gitconnected.com/auto-unsubscribing-in-angular-components-like-a-pro-742220b01d0c

Answer (score 0):

The cli doesn't have a configuration for this, but you can edit the default component template.

The template file is at `node_modules\@schematics\angular\component\files\__name@dasherize@if-flat__\__name@dasherize__.__type@dasherize__.ts.template`

Looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit<% if(!!viewEncapsulation) { %>, ViewEncapsulation<% }%><% if(changeDetection !== 'Default') { %>, ChangeDetectionStrategy<% }%> } from '@angular/core';

@Component({<% if(!skipSelector) {%>
  selector: '<%= selector %>',<%}%><% if(inlineTemplate) { %>
  template: `
    <p>
      <%= dasherize(name) %> works!
    </p>
  `<% } else { %>
  templateUrl: './<%= dasherize(name) %><%= type ? '.' + dasherize(type): '' %>.html'<% } if(inlineStyle) { %>,
  styles: [<% if(displayBlock){ %>
    `
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    `<% } %>
  ]<% } else if (style !== 'none') { %>,
  styleUrls: ['./<%= dasherize(name) %><%= type ? '.' + dasherize(type): '' %>.<%= style %>']<% } %><% if(!!viewEncapsulation) { %>,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.<%= viewEncapsulation %><% } if (changeDetection !== 'Default') { %>,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.<%= changeDetection %><% } %>
})
export class <%= classify(name) %><%= classify(type) %> implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Add in the import, the implements line, and the empty method:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit<% if(!!viewEncapsulation) { %>, ViewEncapsulation<% }%><% if(changeDetection !== 'Default') { %>, ChangeDetectionStrategy<% }%> } from '@angular/core';

@Component({<% if(!skipSelector) {%>
  selector: '<%= selector %>',<%}%><% if(inlineTemplate) { %>
  template: `
    <p>
      <%= dasherize(name) %> works!
    </p>
  `<% } else { %>
  templateUrl: './<%= dasherize(name) %><%= type ? '.' + dasherize(type): '' %>.html'<% } if(inlineStyle) { %>,
  styles: [<% if(displayBlock){ %>
    `
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    `<% } %>
  ]<% } else if (style !== 'none') { %>,
  styleUrls: ['./<%= dasherize(name) %><%= type ? '.' + dasherize(type): '' %>.<%= style %>']<% } %><% if(!!viewEncapsulation) { %>,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.<%= viewEncapsulation %><% } if (changeDetection !== 'Default') { %>,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.<%= changeDetection %><% } %>
})
export class <%= classify(name) %><%= classify(type) %> implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
  }

}
```

Of course the changes won't persist on an update, but it's a quick hack.